# Python hash of identical files comes out different

Tags: python, hash

I've written a simple Python script to copy a file from one place to another. (It's for class, so that's why I'm not using something simpler like `shutil`. I have a check at the end that compares the hash of the two files, and it consistently tells me they're different, even though the copying is successful - both are text files that say "hello world".

Here is my code:

```
import os

def validity_checker(address1, dest_name):
    try:
        src = open(address1, 'rb')
        dest = open(dest_name, 'wb+')
    except IOError:
        return False
    return True


def copaste(address1, address2):
    # concatenate address2 into filename
    file_ending = address1.split('\\').pop()
    dest_name = address2 + '\\' + file_ending

    # copy file after calling checker
    if validity_checker(address1, dest_name):
        src = open(address1, 'rb')
        dest = open(dest_name, 'wb+')
        contents = src.read()
        dest.write(contents)
        src.close()
        dest.close()
    else:
        print("File name bad. No action taken")

    print src
    print dest
    print(hash(src))  #hash the file not the string
    print(hash(dest))
    return
```

And the output:

```
<closed file 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\hello.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x04B7D1D8>
<closed file 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\dest\\hello.txt', mode 'wb+' at 0x04C2B860>
-2042961099
4991878
```

Plus the file is copied.

I'm fairly sure the hash is checking the file itself, not the string. Is it maybe something to do with metadata? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `hash()` is not a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: What is `file` here? You never defined that name. Did you mean `print(hash(src))` perhaps? Not that that'll change the outcome.

Comment: I did, thanks - fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the **Python-specific** [`hash()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash), which calculates a hash for use on *dictionary keys and `set` contents*.

For file objects, the `hash()` is based on the object identity; you can't base it on anything else because two distinct file objects are never *equal*, the `fileobject.__eq__` method returns `True` only if both objects are one and the same in memory (so `is` would be true too). The file contents, the name of the file, the mode or any of the other object attributes play no role in the hash value produced.

From the function documentation:

> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one). Hash values are integers. **They are used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup.**

If you need to validate that the file copy contains the same data, you need to hash the •file contents* using a *cryptographic hash function*, which is something completely different. Use the [`hashlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html); for your usecase the simple and fast `MD5` algorithm will do:

```
for closed_file in (src, dest):
    with open(closed_file.name, 'rb') as reopened:  # opened in binary mode!
        print(reopened.name)
        print(hashlib.md5(reopened.read()).hexdigest())
```

If the binary contents of the two files is exactly the same, then their cryptographic hash will also be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I feel very foolish. However, even after switching to the hashlib library, the problem still exists. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Please don’t do that; your original error has been resolved , you have a new problem warranting a new question. I’ve rolled back your edit. Your new problem is that you didn’t reopen the `src` file, nor did you do a seek back to the start so `src.read()` produces an empty string the second time. You are comparing the hash of `b''` so the comparison fails. Please do use the code I posted in my answer!

Comment: My apologies for the breach of etiquette, and thanks once again for the help. I'd assumed that closing and re-opening the file couldn't have been important - now I know better!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the python hash of the `file` object. Not the contents of the file. As a minimum you should

```
print(hash(open(address1, 'rb').read())
print(hash(open(dest_name, 'rb').read())
```

But since this still risks collisions, you should do as Martijn suggests and use a `hashlib` function.